# Error converting Simple Captcha to string using tesseract

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, webautomation

I want to automate some login processes for a ticketing system. There is a simple captcha at the login screen. I am able to take a partial snapshot of it, but as soon as I send that image to image_to_string() function, there is a error. The error says:

> "[Win Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

[image: The Code]

[image: The Error]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but why are you saving an image just to open it again in the very next line? Just pass the image directly into tesseract...

Comment: @Rawing I did that it doesn't help. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not that tesseract can't find your image, it's that Windows can't find tesseract.

pytesseract internally runs `subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', input_file])`, and this throws the error. But if you try `subprocess.Popen(['tesseract'])`, you'll get the exact same error.

If you read the [installation instructions](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#installation) you'll see:

> You must be able to invoke the tesseract command as *tesseract*.

And:

> If this isn't the case, for example because tesseract isn't in your PATH, you will have to change the "tesseract_cmd" variable at the top of tesseract.py

So you can either add tesseract to your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) or modify the `tesseract_cmd` to point directly to your tesseract executable.